# Creating a Custom Gradle task of type msbuild

Tags: gradle, msbuild

I'm currently running

gradle 4.0.1

groovy 2.4.11

JVM 1.8.0_131

and I'm attempting to create a custom task that will execute two different Visual Studio solutions. I have abc.sln and xyz.sln and I would like to have one gradle script that can call either of the two solutions to build.

```
buildscript 
{
    repositories 
    {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies 
    {
        classpath "com.ullink.gradle:gradle-msbuild-plugin:2.9"
    }
}

msbuild { 
    group = "Custom"

    solutionFile = 'abc.sln'
    projectName = project.name
    configuration = 'Debug'
    //verbosity = 'detailed' 
    targets = ['Clean', 'Rebuild']
}

apply plugin 'msbuild'
```

and I want to have another task

```
task msbuild2 (type: msbuild) {
    group = "Custom"

    solutionFile = 'xyz.sln'
    projectName = project.name
    configuration = 'Release'
    //verbosity = 'detailed' 
    targets = ['Clean', 'Rebuild']
}
```

however I get the error:

> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Windows'.
>
> com.ullink.Msbuild_Decorated cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

Any ideas on how to create a custom task of type msbuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must pass the task type by its class name here. the class name is `com.ullink.Msbuild`. So you can either do

```
import com.ullink.Msbuild

task myMsBuild(type:Msbuild){
    ...
    ...
}
```

or

```
task myMsBuild(type: com.ullink.Msbuild){
    ...
    ...
}
```

BTW: Case sensitivity matters here!